# Is an Element an instance of a Node in HTML?

Tags: html, nodes, element

Is an Element an instance of a Node in HTML?

I presume Attributes are also Nodes and that "the Elements" is the set of Nodes that can be defined using the angle-bracket syntax?

Comment: "An XML element is everything from (including) the element's start tag to (including) the element's end tag."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a `Node`, according to the [MDN documentation for `HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) :

> Inherits properties from its parents **`Node`**, and its own parent, `EventTarget`, and implements those of `ParentNode`, `ChildNode`, `NonDocumentTypeChildNode`, and `Animatable`.

If that's a bit hard to find in text, MDN also provides an "Inheritance section" in the left sidebar.

> [image: MDN sidebar]

Answer (score 3):

> **Properties**
>
> Inherits properties from its parents [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), and its own parent, `EventTarget`, and implements those of `ParentNode`, `ChildNode`, `NonDocumentTypeChildNode`, and `Animatable`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element