# Roles and responsibilties inherited in this browser object's hierarchy

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, javascript-objects

In the below hierarchy of browser objects,

### [image]

Each object in the above hierarchy would have been created to target certain scope of responsibilities to manage html elements.

In the above hierarchy, Can you please outline the roles & responsibilities of each browser object including `Object` that are inherited by its child?

Comment: @Sam  I do not know the purpose of Nodejs. am new to JS.

Comment: Have you tried the MDN documentation:
- [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
- [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)
- [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node)
- [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)
- [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

Might be a bit advanced for somebody new to JS but could be a good place to get some ideas from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot at some basics.

Nodes are basically every item in the DOM including text nodes.

Elements are a subset of nodes which have html tags.  The element level also holds the API for a number of high-level generic attributes and event handling that all of the HTML elements share.

Elements and nodes have parent/child relationships which can be traversed, iterated over, etc.

The event target is essentially a node at a point in time when an event has fired;  which is the object passed to the event handler that is set on that node for that specific event.  E.g. the button that I just clicked.

HTML elements are essentially different tags which have certain basic looks and feels. So there's lots of default CSS and supported eventing this level.  Also certain HTML elements can only be children of other certain ones.  Think schema.

I think object is pretty self explanatory, for object-oriented purposes (prototypes, instantiation, etc). The thing that comes to mind when I see that though, is that it would be the spot on the graph which would be responsible for JSON serialization.

Comment: For example: property names `removeChild` `appendChild` say that  `Node` handles a responsibility of  maintening an html element. So, without mentioning each property name, I need outline of responsibilities of each object in that hierarchy, without getting into API specifics

Comment: @overexchange That's what I'm trying to say for node and element, they deal with all the parent-child stuff. If you're looking for specifics down to the API level, I don't think we'll be able to address that in this thread without just linking you to some documentation.

Comment: Can you share the reference to any documentation that talks about the roles and responsibilities?

Answer (score 0):

**Object**
`Object` is not necessarily browser related. Javascript in a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) environment, for example also has Object. It is similar to `Object` in Java. It represents the most generic, basic form of object and forms the basis of Object Oriented Programming in Javascript. All objects in Javascript inherit from `Object`.
*Roles & Responsibilities*: It is there to act as the *base class* of all classes and provide simple methods like `toString()` and `is()` (similar to Java's `isEqual`).

**Node and Element**
See: [What's the difference between an element and a node in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132564/3649209)
and: [Is an Element an instance of a Node in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33652571/3649209)

[`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node) and [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) represent nodes are related to DOM trees and are inspired by XML's definition of *Node* and *Element*. A [DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) is a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) representation of XML. A **node** represents *anything* in the tree (a comment, a ctag, a tag, an attribute). An **element** is specifically, nodes that are *tags* (`<div>`, `<h1>`, `<span>`, `<g>`, `<clipPath>`, `<circle>`, ...). By this definition, every element is a node (Element inherits from Node).
*Roles & Responsibilities*: `Node` is there to provide a useful abstraction for manipulating a DOM tree. Methods like traversing the tree, adding nodes, removing nodes, finding childing. `Element` has the same role but is there when we specifically deals with tags. It has extra methods specific to tags like `Element.tagName()`.

**HTMLElement, SVGElement, ...**
The two most common types of XML the browser deals with is HTML and SVG. But there are more. For example [MathML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element) is XML for writing maths equations in the browser. [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGElement) is a subclass of `Element` for HTML tags (`<div>`, `<h1>`, `<span>`, ...). [`SVGElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGElement) is a subclass of `Element` used for SVG tags (`<g>`, `<clipPath>`, `<circle>`, ...).
*Roles & Responsibilities*: `HTMLElement` and `SVGElement` are mainly needed to keep the inheritance tree organised. Programmers can use `instanceof` on a `Element` to see whether they are dealing with HTML or SVG or some other kind of XML the browser supports. `HTMLElement` has some methods for accessibility like 
`SVGElement` has some methods related to the SVG viewport.

**HTMLSpanElement, HTMLDivElement, ...**
Every HTML tag, `<Foo>`, has a corresponding Javascript class `<HTMLFooElement>`. These are all subclasses of `HTMLElement`. Similarly every SVG element, `<Bar>` has a corresponding class `<SVGBarElement>`. So for `<span>`, `<div>`, etc. ... we have [`HTMLSpanElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSpanElement) and [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement). Likewise for SVG's `<g>` and `<circle>` elements, we have [`SVGGElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGGElement) and [`SVGCircleElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGCircleElement).
*Roles & Responsibilities*: Again these classes are used to keep the inheritance tree organised. It is convenient to give a OOP type for each particular element and have element-specific methods and properties. SVG circle has properties for x position, y position and radius, for example.

**EventTarget**
This is more of an *interface* than a class. It is similar to the observer pattern. Any class that implements this [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) is able to register several subscribers via `addEventListener` and then later, send an event to the subscribers.
*Roles & Responsibilities*: It is [useful](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) for listening to events such as clicks, keyboard presses, etc.
For example, if you click on a `<div>`, the browser will call `dispatchEvent` on the `HTMLDivELement` and anyone will have subscribed will have their callback function invoked.